# Segfault in gdb after fork and PROT_EXEC remove

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb, maps, fork

I built a shared library (.so) and a binary that use this library.
The binary and the shared library are then mapped in different places :

```
555555554000-555555555000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 42348564                   /tmp/binary
...
7ffff7bd6000-7ffff7bd7000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 42348636                   /tmp/libperso.so
...
```

The binary simply call a function in the library.
That function removes the PROT_EXEC right of `binary` but keep the execution right of the library, meaning that the address space is changed from

```
555555554000-555555555000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 42348564                   /tmp/binary
...
7ffff7bd6000-7ffff7bd7000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 42348636                   /tmp/libperso.so
...
```

to

```
555555554000-555555555000 r--p 00000000 08:21 42348564                   /tmp/binary
...
7ffff7bd6000-7ffff7bd7000 r-xp 00000000 08:21 42348636                   /tmp/libperso.so
...
```

When executing the code, all is working fine.
However, executing it inside gdb induces a segmentation fault.
More precisly I just set a breakpoint at symbol `main` in the executable and a breakpoint at symbol `myfunction` in the library, and then I execute it:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
$ gdb binary
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
(gdb) b myfunction
(gdb) c
(gdb) si -----> SIGSEGV in myfunction
```

The instruction that induces a segmentation fault is :

```
=> 0x00007ffff7bd680e <+4>:     nop
```

This is in `/tmp/libperso.so` that is mapped in an executable address space.
The question is why I have this segmentation fault in gdb ?

The executable code looks like

```
void dowork(void);
int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
      dowork ();
}
```

The library code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
void myfunction(void)
{
  return;
}
void
dowork (void)
{
  /* get the binary location in the child address space*/ 
  int saveprot;
  void *saveaddr;
  size_t savesize;
  FILE *mapsfile = fopen ("/proc/self/maps", "r");
  char *lineptr = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  getline (&lineptr, &n, mapsfile);
  long addrStart = strtoull (lineptr, NULL, 16);
  lineptr = strstr (lineptr, "-") + 1;
  long addrEnd = strtoull (lineptr, NULL, 16);
  lineptr = strstr (lineptr, " ") + 1;
  saveprot = PROT_NONE;
  if (lineptr[0] != '-')
   saveprot  |= PROT_READ;
  if (lineptr[1] != '-')
   saveprot  |= PROT_WRITE;
  if (lineptr[2] != '-')
   saveprot  |= PROT_EXEC;
  saveaddr = (void *)addrStart;
  savesize = addrEnd - addrStart;

  /* remove PROT_EXEC */
  if(mprotect(saveaddr,savesize,saveprot ^ PROT_EXEC) != 0)
  {
    perror("mprotect");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* do things */
  myfunction();

  /* restore PROT_EXEC */
  if(mprotect(saveaddr,savesize,saveprot) != 0)
  {
    perror("mprotect");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And the Makefile :

```
all:
    gcc -g -c -Wall -fpic perso.c
    gcc -g -shared -o libperso.so perso.o
    rm perso.o
    gcc -Wall -g -o binary main.c -L. -lperso 
run:
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./binary
clean:
    rm -f binary libperso.so
```

Comment: Note that if I don't set a breakpoint at `myfunction`, all is working fine in gdb

Comment: Also there is no trace of the SIGSEGV when I execute `dmesg`. Maybe a simple bug in gdb ?